# How to remove array boundary quotes in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have an ajax call which will respond a comma separated values. I want change this value into an array.

Here is my example

```
$.ajax
 ({             
     url: url, 
     type: 'post', 
     data: Data, 
     success: function(response)
     {
         console.log([response]);  
     }
});
```

In this response will be

```
'Alappuzha','Beypur','Cheruvannur','Edakkara','Edathala','Kalamassery'
```

like this

I am converting it into an array  So [response] is shows

```
["'Alappuzha','Beypur','Cheruvannur','Edakkara','Edathala','Kalamassery'"]
```

like this

But I don't want a boundary quotes

Here is my php Code

```
foreach($citydata as $keyrow):
     $citylist[]= "'".$keyrow['location_name']."'";  
endforeach; 
$dataCity = implode(",",$citylist); 
print($dataCity);
exit;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why can't you fix it in the server side? and return an array

Comment: Can you show the `PHP` code also?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the Response?? Do you want it as an array? Please share the backend code as well

Comment: try this -> response = response.split(',')

Comment: Why aren't you just printing json from your php code? Why do you print comma separated?

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution will to fix it in the server side itself and return a proper string array to the client.

If that is not possible, you can split the string by `,` then process each item and remove the starting and ending `'`

```js
var response = "'Alappuzha','Beypur','Cheruvannur','Edakkara','Edathala','Kalamassery'";
var array = response.split(',').map(function(value) {
  return value.replace(/^'|'$/g, '')
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

With the PHP

```
foreach($citydata as $keyrow):
     $citylist[]= $keyrow['location_name'];  
endforeach; 
print(json_encode($dataCity));
exit;
```

then just use the response as it is

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'post',
  data: Data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: In response its not have double quate

Comment: only after adding in square brackets its comming

Comment: @Athi that is just a string notation... now `response` is a string array.. so the `"` is just used to denote that

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change your php code to echo json?

```
foreach($citydata as $keyrow):
             $citylist[]= "'".$keyrow['location_name']."'";
        endforeach; 
        print(json_encode($dataCity));
        exit;
```

then you also don't have to do this anymore:

```
         console.log([response]);
```

just do this:

```
     console.log(response);
```

Comment: Why are the quotes needed when you use JSON?

Comment: @Barmar, these are not needed, but the asker wants those.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var resp ="'Alappuzha','Beypur','Cheruvannur','Edakkara','Edathala','Kalamassery'" ;
var str = "["+resp+"]"
console.log(str.replace(/"(.+)"/g, '$1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In response its not have double quate

Answer (score 0):

*try this*

```
success: function(response)
{
    var myArray=response.split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `response.split(",")` to convert the string that you are getting into an array. or you can echo `json_encode($citylist)` instead of imploding it. That way you will get a proper JSON string in the client side that you can easily handle with JS.